# Can I use Wandb in Tracking my YOLOv4 Training?

Tags: yolov4, wandb

I want to track my training in YOLOv4 using wandb but I can't see any tutorial on how to do it. I saw a youtube video but it was a training in YOLOv5.

My wandb account is now logged in in the YOLOv4  training but I cant see no chart in the wandb page. It only displays this page [Wandb YOLOv4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaAjB.png)

I want to know how exactly I can use wandb in my YOLOv4 training.

Comment: @zeninging hi. I'm from wandb. We might not have an integration with the repository that you're using. Can you point me to the YOLOv4 repo you're using so I can have a look?

Comment: @AyushChaurasia hello, this was the colab link i used. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mzL6WyY9BRx4xX476eQdhKDnd_eixBlG#scrollTo=GNVU7eu9CQj3

Comment: this repo owned by roboflow doesn't have wandb integration. The official yolov3, yolov4, and yolov5 repos have wandb integration. You'll get the plots if you use them

Comment: @AyushChaurasia ok thank you very much ill try using it

Comment: @AyushChaurasia can i use this link? https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_GdoqCJWXsChrOiY8sZMr_zbr_fH-0Fg?usp=sharing